# How to apply softedges to an Outlook email photo

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Here's the issue - I have an auto generating email from Excel and it sets two images in the email in a table. I want those two images to have softedges. Using VBA to solve the problem in the email, how can I do this?

I would think that the email has to be displayed then modify the shape.softedges.type = msoSoftEdgeType2

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Word object model model to modify the email body. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document class which represents the message body. You can read more about all possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

The Shape class from the Word object model provides the [SoftEdge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196696(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a SoftEdgeFormat object that represents the soft edge formatting for a shape. The SoftEdgeFormat class provides the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821955(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns or sets an MsoBevelType constant that represents the bevel type for the edges of images that use soft edge formatting.